# PyQt/PySide: Handle Barcode Reader Input

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, barcode-scanner, keyboard-events

In my GUI (written in PySide 6), I want to allow user input through the keyboard (e.g., in a text field), and I want to handle input from a barcode reader (e.g., scanning of a barcode runs a bunch of actions in sequence).

The barcode reader behaves like a keyboard and triggers `QKeyEvent`s for every character in the barcode. All those events are triggered in quick succession. At the end of the barcode, `Key_Enter` is triggered.

My implementation currently uses an `eventFilter` to catch all the keyboard inputs independent of the widget in focus. It looks like this (reduced to the essentials):

```
import sys
import time

from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QObject
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # SHOW APP
        self.show()


class BarcodeEventFilter(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent: MainWindow):
        QObject.__init__(self)

        self.main_window = parent
        self.input_buffer = ''
        self.last_keypress = time.time()

    def handle_barcode_input(self, input_string):
        print(f'Barcode received: {input_string}')

    def eventFilter(self,
                    watched: QtCore.QObject,
                    event: QtCore.QEvent) -> bool:
        # verbose output for debugging:
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            print(f'{event.text()} - {type(watched)}')
            
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress \
                and type(watched) == QtGui.QWindow:
            if time.time() - self.last_keypress < 1e-1:
                if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return):
                    if len(self.input_buffer) > 1:
                        self.main_window.handle_barcode_input(
                            self.input_buffer)
                        self.input_buffer = ''
                else:
                    self.input_buffer += event.text()
            else:
                self.input_buffer = event.text()

            self.last_keypress = time.time()
            # return True would cause that no user input through keyboard is possible.
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    barcode_event_filter = BarcodeEventFilter(parent=window)
    app.installEventFilter(barcode_event_filter)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The trouble is that now all the `KeyPress` events are handled by the underlying widgets, no matter if they originate from the user keyboard or the barcode scanner. This can cause unwanted GUI interactions depending on the text in the barcode.

If the `eventFilter` returns True, all keyboard input is blocked. So this is also not a solution.

I wonder if there is a better way of handling input from these different devices. For example: Is there a way to buffer all `KeyPress` events for a few milliseconds to see if it is a barcode (closing on a `Key_Enter`)? If it is a barcode, process it, if not, release all the `KeyPress` events that have been on hold.

Any input is welcome - pun intended ;-)

Comment: That's tricky, and also depends on important aspects, for instance: 1. the reader type (some readers provide system configuration that allows input modifications, so you may insert a "prefix" before any captured string); whether you need to provide generic readers or not may also be important; 2. if the target should always be a single, specific widget, or it's also allowed to enter bar codes for different "fields"; 3. the target OS (some platforms allow more specific native event filtering); 4. whether the normal input is expected to act relatively fast or not.

Comment: Why not try to implement your ad-hoc filtering logic? You can call the ```QCoreApplication.postEvent()``` to post events blocked by an event filter.

Comment: @musicamante 1: I have two different readers that should work. At least one doesn't seem to sorry prefixes. 2: It's okay if all barcodes are handled by the filter and are not forwarded to any other widget, like line edits. 3: Windows 10/11 4: The user experience should not be impacted, so I'd say no more than 10 ms delay.